# How to reconnect a previously connected SOCK_STREAM socket to another server

Tags: sockets, tcp, python-3.4, python-sockets

Is it possible to create a SOCK_STREAM socket in python, which can be used to communicate with many servers one-by-one ?. 
For ex-
a) First connect to a server1
b) Exchange few messages with server1
c) close connection with server1
d) Using the same socket connect with server2
e) Exchange few messages with server2
f) close connection with server2
g) Repeat the above steps.
If it is possible then How?

Comment: You can't. You have to close the socket and create and connect a new one.

Comment: Re your edit, (d) is impossible. Why do you think you need this? What's the outer problem here?

Comment: Only on Windows using WinSock, it is actually possible to reuse a socket handle after its connection is closed, but doing so requires using special extensions to the WinSock API. But using BSD style socket APIs, it is simply not possible to reuse a socket after it is closed.

Comment: @user207421 I encountered the problem, while working on client module in my project. After I knew, it's not possible, I changed my implementation.